# Prettier react/jsx-max-props-per-line format with VSCode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, prettier

I use Prettier in JavaScript project with React. All my component props is formated in 1 line :

`<Icon icon="arrow-left" width={15} height={18} />`

And i would like this :

```
<Icon
  icon="arrow-left"
  width={15}
  height={18}
/>
```

I've add `"react/jsx-max-props-per-line": [1, { "when": "multiline" }]` to my .prettierrc, but no result.

I've an ESLint config too, with this rules :

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["react", "prettier", "standard"],
  "rules": {
    "indent": [2, 2, { "SwitchCase": 1 }],
    "quotes": [2, "single"],
    "linebreak-style": [2, "unix"],
    "semi": [2, "always"],
    "no-console": [0],
    "no-loop-func": [0],
    "new-cap": [0],
    "no-trailing-spaces": [0],
    "no-param-reassign": [0],
    "func-names": [0],
    "comma-dangle": [0],
    "no-unused-expressions": [0],
    "block-scoped-var": [0],
    "react/prop-types": [0],
    "prettier/prettier": "error"
  }
}
```

My .prettier file config :

```
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
  "printWidth": 80,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": [1, { "when": "always" }]
```

Maybe a conflict ? I've try to move the `react/jsx-max-props-per-line` to ESLint rules, but no result too. No change.

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 18):

Since Prettier `2.6.0` you can [enforce single attribute per line](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#single-attribute-per-line) in HTML or JSX if you add the following to your config:

```
"singleAttributePerLine": true
```

Comment: This is the answer I have been looking for. You can add this line to your .prettierrc file on root.

Comment: creating a `.prettierrc` file and adding this line there worked for me.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

I was able to get it to work with the following:

```
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'react-app',
    'prettier',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  plugins: ['prettier'],
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-first-prop-new-line': [2, 'multiline'],
    'react/jsx-max-props-per-line': [
      2,
      { maximum: 1, when: 'multiline' },
    ],
    'react/jsx-indent-props': [2, 2],
    'react/jsx-closing-bracket-location': [
      2,
      'tag-aligned',
    ],
  },
}

// .prettierrc
{
 "semi": false,
 "singleQuote": true,
 "printWidth":80 // default
}
```

Along with my dev dependencies which is essentially from [eslint-config-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-react-app)

```
"devDependencies": {
"@types/node": "^14.6.0",
"@types/react": "^16.9.46",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.0.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.0.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.0",
"eslint": "^7.5.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
"eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
"eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.3",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.8",
"eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^3.9.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"prettier": "^2.2.1",
"typescript": "4.0.5"
},
```

Which formats the code **ONLY** if the line exceeds `printWidth: 80` characters.

```html
<InputField name="password" placeholder="password" label="Password" type="password" />
  
// transforms to this if line exceeds 'printWidth'

<InputField
  name="username"
  placeholder="username"
  label="Username"
  type="text" 
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
module.exports = {
    'extends': [
        'eslint:recommended',

    ],
    'env': {
        'es6': true
    },
    'plugins': ['react'],
    'parser': 'babel-eslint',
    'rules': {

        // you rules....

        'react/jsx-first-prop-new-line': [1, 'multiline'],
        'react/jsx-max-props-per-line': [1,
            {
                'maximum': 1
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

`yarn add --dev prettier-eslint-cli`

VS code userConfig

`"prettier.eslintIntegration": true,`

Comment: prettier.eslintIntegration is greyed out because it is an unknown configuration setting

Comment: You would need to install the Prettier extension for VSCode first. VSCode doesn't include Prettier out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to only change line for props on save with Prettier in Vscode then there is an option to do that.

In settings.json add the following line

```
"prettier.printWidth": 100,
```

[image]

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you should only ESLint rules to your ESLint config, not your `.prettierrc` file.. they will be ignored since they're not valid Prettier configuration. Also, ESLint does not affect Prettier behavior. You can run Prettier via ESLint (as an auto-fixable rule via [`eslint-plugin-prettier`](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier)) or run Prettier and run ESLint after, using [`prettier-eslint`](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint)) which VSCode uses if you have `prettier.eslintIntegration` turned on.

Now you probably need to change the ESLint rule to use `{"when": "always"}` option. According to the [docs](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-max-props-per-line.md#when), using `"multiline"` will only complain if your component is already multiline, but you have more than 1 prop per line:

```
<Icon 
  icon="arrow-left"
  widht={15} height={18}
/>
```

Using `"always"` will never allow more than 1 prop per line, even when the tag is not originally multiline.

Comment: Hi Lucas, i've try with `always` (on .prettierrc file), but same result : no change

Comment: Hi @s-leg3ndz I've edited my answer to clarify that ESLint rules live on ESlint configuration and not on .prettierrc

Comment: I think i understand. I've edit my first post, with the config after add `eslint-plugin-prettier`. But, my component is a new time formated in 1 line :/

Comment: In the updated post the `react/jsx-max-props-per-line` is still on `.prettierrc` and not on the ESLint config.

Comment: It does not work either. There is something that I must do wrong .. I will study the two docs and see what's wrong, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `"react/jsx-max-props-per-line"` is not a valid prettier rule, it's a rule of ESLint. I suggest keeping this rule in ESLint config file, but also set your editor to make all possible ESLint fixes on save.

You can turn on linting on save by following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/workflow-auto-eslinting#adding-vscode-autosave). Or just put these:

```
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "eslint.validate": ["javascript"]
```

lines in your user or local workspace *settings.json* object. This will solve your problem.

In my experience Prettier and ESLint auto-formatting can work well together.